# Ubuntu 20.04 Deemix launching error

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, virtualization, vmware, qt

I get the following error when I try to open an executable file with `./deemix-pyweb`:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

I have a fresh VMware installation with Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded `deemix-linux-x64.zip` from the deemix official Telegram group.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal in the decompressed folder and run these commands:

```
chmod a+x deemix-pyweb
./deemix-pyweb
```

Comment: still the same error.